# Post-email-verification hook

Tags: stormpath, express-stormpath

In express-stormpath, what's the best way to run some code after a successful email verification?

`postRegistrationHandler` comes close, but it gets called before email verification.

Answer (score 1):

We don't yet have a hook for this, although we're working on writing a new events system at some point in the future, at which point this will get added =)

If you'd like to get us to add this feature, leave a comment on our Github tracker here: https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath/issues (we listen to feedback!)